# Running multiple Wordpress sites on a single domain/web server

Tags: wordpress

I have a rather general but very important question. I have built a main website and an eShop for a client. The main website is in Wordpress and I have to find a platform for the eShop, but let's say it's also a Wordpress theme.

Can I install 2 wordpress sites in my hosting server? So for example, the first one will be www.company.com/website and the other being www.company.com/shop.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can: [Installing Multiple Blogs « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs).

Comment: And, in this particular case, you can even do the shop and website with a single blog/install.

Answer (score 4):

While all the previous answers are technically correcct - they will have you doing twice the work that is actually needed for your desired outcome (as in two installs, two upgrades, two sets of security checks, two databases, two admin panels... you get the idea - two times the work, all unnecessary).

Since Wordpress 3.0, the WordpressMU features have been integrated into the core. This allows you to run multiple Wordprsss 'sites' from a single install.

Sites can be served from their different domain, sub-domains, or in your case different sub-directories within the same domain and server.

Full information on how to achieve this is available from Wordpress Codex:
[Create A Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Comment: It also makes much more easy to keep your your WordPress site updated an thus, secure

Comment: Well, what if the site is too big, and threfore have separate installs would allow you to keep up to date just the most important modules of the site? (this might occur for some commercial reason)

Answer (score 0):

Just install one wordpress app in your root directory and create the other directory and install it there, there should be no problem.

Comment: as for @thewinchester answer, there is no need to have multiple WordPress installs to run multiple sites. It works, but it's double work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that if you are routing around a port 80 blockade (aka using a different port to host your site) then Multi-site WILL NOT WORK.  In such an instance multiple WP installations seem to be the ticket.

Answer (score -5):

You can choose a directory relative to your root domain when installing wordpress on your site.